# Dragging a CSS Rotated Image Within a Div

Tags: jquery, css, image, draggable, transform

I haven't been able to quite find the solution to my problem here...

I am basically creating something like the Facebook thumbnail editor where the user can move an image around to the visible portion they desire.

It works fine except I also want them to be able to rotate the image in 90deg intervals only.  Here is where the problem comes in.

The contanier div that constrains the movement to within the visible box is updated via jQuery when the user hits the rotate button.  The dimensions of the constraining div seem to be correct according to the math.  However, the rotated image does not move within the constraining div properly.  It seems bound by some other dimensions.  Sometimes goes outside the boundary of the constraining div.

How can I get the rotated image to move freely within in the constraining div?  Do I need to do something with transform-origin?  Although my origin should always be in the center of the image regardless of rotation?

jQuery:

```
var rotValue = 0;

$("a[id='rotate']").click(function(e) {

    rotValue +=90;          
    if (rotValue == 360) {rotValue = 0;}

    var wd = $('#photo-in-edit').width();
    var ht = $('#photo-in-edit').height();      

    $('#photo-in-edit').css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+rotValue+'deg)');
    $('#photo-in-edit').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+rotValue+'deg)');
    $('#photo-in-edit').css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+rotValue+'deg)');
    $('#photo-in-edit').css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+rotValue+'deg)');


    if ((rotValue == 0) || (rotValue == 180)){
        createCont(wd, ht);  //calls the function below to resize the container
    } else {        
        createCont(ht, wd);
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;

});

function createCont (w, h) {

    var containerHeight, containerTop, containerWidth, containerLeft;

    //the dimensions of my viewable area are 600 x 400  
    var xOverflow = (w - 600);
    var yOverflow = (h - 400);

    if (xOverflow < 0) {containerHeight = 400;containerTop = 0;}
    else {containerHeight = ((h * 2) - 400);containerTop = (yOverflow*-1);}

    if (yOverflow < 0) {containerWidth = 600;containerLeft = 0;}
    else {containerWidth = ((w * 2) - 600);containerLeft = (xOverflow*-1);}

    $('#photo-container').css('top', containerTop+"px");
    $('#photo-container').css('height', containerHeight+"px");
    $('#photo-container').css('left', containerLeft+"px");
    $('#photo-container').css('width', containerWidth+"px");
    $('#photo-in-edit').css('top', "");
    $('#photo-in-edit').css('left',""); 

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="photo-edit-box" >
    <div id="photo-container" >
        <img id="photo-in-edit" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Oud_Poelgeest_Oegstgeest.jpg" />
    </div><!--photo-container-->
</div><!--photo-edit-box-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find something workable and it turns out to be quite simple.

I got the answer from this page:  [Dragging & Resizing CSS Transformed Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007971/dragging-resizing-css-transformed-elements?rq=1)
.

One of the lower answers using separate divs for dragging and rotation.

Comment: This answer should be down voted. You need to provide the actual answer here and not link to somewhere else. Please fix.